# Call immediately executing function from outside

Tags: javascript

I've got an immediately executing function and I need to call it from outside:

```
(function myFunc(){    
  console.log("Hello from myFunc");
})();
```

I'm using named function because I'm doing a recursion in it so I can reference it. but at some point recursion stops. and I need to invoke this function once again.

Comment: When you only use it for the initial call and the recursion from *inside* the `myFunc` body, it should work. Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you have to wrap it like that? Why don't you just make a normal named function and call it:

```
function myFunc(){    
  console.log("Hello from myFunc");
}
myfunc();
```

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing that just now =), but I'm still curious if this is possible.

Comment: Spidermonkey, at least, doesn't see the name after your statement.

Comment: wrapping the code in brackets as Headshota shows is the propper syntax (as per JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov).